# Laravel advance routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

The following is the route

```
Route::get('{value1}/{optvalue1?}/{optvalue2?}/{value2}/{value3}/',
        [
            'uses'  => 'Controller@control',
            'as'    => 'path_route'
        ]
    );
```

My controller is setup as follows

```
function redirectSearchRequest(){

return redirect()->route('path_route', [
        $value1,
        isset($optvalue1) ? $optvalue1 : '',
        isset($optvalue2) ? $optvalue2 : '',
       $value2,
       $value3
    ]);

}


public function control($value1, $iptvalue1 = null, $optvalue2 = null, $value2, $value3)
{
    //process accordingly
}
```

Now the problem with this is 
if I had a `url` which look like `http://example.com/value1/optvalue1/optvalue2/value2/value3`. It works without any errors but the url can be sometimes without `optvlaue1` and `optvalue2` and the route returns `http://example.com/value1////value2/value3` as expected laravel throws `NotFoundHttpException`.

Further more to this problem `Option` variable are not always present but when they are they should be exactly like how the route is set. I cannot change the order around :(.

Hopefully I am clear enough. 
Cheers for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Optional variables work better when they're at the end, to avoid 404 errors like you are seeing. There are several workaround you can try:

**Option 1:**

Account for every possible variation of the route:

```
Route::get('{value1}/{optvalue1?}/{optvalue2?}/{value2}/{value3}/', Controller@control );
Route::get('{value1}/{optvalue1?}/{value2}/{value3}/', Controller@control );
Route::get('{value1}/{optvalue2?}/{value2}/{value3}/', Controller@control );
Route::get('{value1}/{value2}/{value3}/', Controller@control );
```

**Option 2:**

Use the optional parameters in query string

```
Route::get('{value1}/{value2}/{value3}/', Controller@control );
```

And just add `?optvalue1=something&optvalue2=something-else`

Otherwise, it gets very complicated in identifying which parameter is which.

**Option 3:**

Another solution could be to default the values of `optvalue1` and `optvalue2` to something. E.g.

```
http://example.com/value1/null/null/value2/value3
```